# How to exclude background image?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have below css in style.css.

```
.mobile-base{
 background-image:url("img/mobile-base.png");
 background-size:cover;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 width:312px;
 height:552px;
 margin-bottom:-8px;
 display: inline-block;
}
```

And below html markups

```
<div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8 someclass">
    <div id="app-body-105">
       <div class="mobile-base">
         <img class="img-responsive alignleft" src="http://192.168.0.31/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/app-1.jpg" alt="">
       </div>

      <div class="content-base">
      <h2>The Ultimate Night Out</h2>
         <p>Phasellus semper massa sit amet metus dictum bibendum. 
        Donec at dui ipsum. Maecenas sagittis tincidunt magna. Proin 
        vulputate mauris  porttitor semper venenatis. Nulla quis sem eget dolor eleifend elementum id at lorem
       </p>      
 </div>
 </div>
```

I want to animate the image on some click event(any random `ID`) inside class `mobile-base` (the image with src) excluding the background image defined in css.

I tried something like below but it animates both images,I don't want background image to be animated.

```
$("#someID").click(function() {
    $('#app-body-105' .mobile-base').show('slow');
});
```

How can I do it with jQuery or JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to animate the image you must tell jQuery to only animate said element:

```
$("#someID").click(function() {
    $('#app-body-105 .mobile-base img').show('slow');
});
```

Comment: Sorry,it's not working.In my code it was animating but both images but I only want the image inside div with class mobile-base(app-.jpg).

Comment: Well, I can't test it if you don't provide an example. But my point is if you animate an element containing another inside, this child element is also going to animate, so you should be targeting exclusively the element you want to animate.